# Value does not fall within the expected range Adding a page to a Subsite

Tags: wiki-pages

I get the error **Value does not fall within the expected range**
when I try to add a page to a wiki library in a **subsite**.
The code works fine if **urlspsite** points to the site collection

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(urlspsite)) 
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists[tbLibrarySP.Text];
                    SPFolder rootFolder = list.RootFolder;

                    SPFile fileAlready = web.GetFile(rootFolder.Name  + "/newpage.aspx");
                    if (!fileAlready.Exists) { 
// the following line gives an ArgumentException Value does not fall within the expected range
                        SPFile wikiPage = rootFolder.Files.Add(String.Format("/{0}/{1}", rootFolder, "newpage.aspx"), SPTemplateFileType.WikiPage);
           ...                    
          }
      ...                    
     } 
     ...                    
    }
```

What could cause the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I see I forgot to add the subsite prefix when adding the file:

So

```
SPFile wikiPage = rootFolder.Files.Add(String.Format("/{0}/{1}", rootFolder, "newpage.aspx"), SPTemplateFileType.WikiPage);
```

should be:

```
SPFile wikiPage = rootFolder.Files.Add(String.Format("/mysubsite/{0}/{1}", rootFolder, "newpage.aspx"), SPTemplateFileType.WikiPage);
```